# How to find passphrase for Lua maked in cocos game?

Tags: decryption, lua

I tried to decompile and find `main.lua` in file (link below) with IDA Pro but it wasn't helpful, because every lua file has it own signature and there is no key near string `main.lua`.
I also tried to find strings such `xxtea` as I found by search, but there is no string in the file.

Screenshot:

[image: ApplicationDidFinishLaunching function]

[Link to download file(google drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1owWBG8oLFWytgS-Xw1_qGuLqaA-SQZao/view?usp=sharing)

But I can't understand how to chain this data to encryption

I would be grateful for any advice and further ideas.